# C programming - loop

Tags: loops

Hello I am starting to learn programming and I would like to know this if someone could help me out.

If we know how many times will loop be done whats the easiest one to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use as a rule of thumb.
If know iterations --> `for`

If unknown iterations --> `while`

If at least one iteration (but not known) --> `repeat`